# Appending divs to a div to create a grid of divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/prashanthcr/cv5c3cah/1/

HTML

```
<h2 id="header">Etch-a-Sketch!</h2>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
<input id="size" type="number" value="10">
<button id="button">New Grid</button>
```

JS (Jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cellsPerSide = $("#size").val();
    var cellSize = $("#grid").width() / cellsPerSide;
    $(".cell").css({"width": cellSize, "height": cellSize, "opacity": "1"})

    for (var i = 0; i < cellsPerSide * cellsPerSide; i++) {
        $("#grid").append("<div class='cell'></div>");
    }

});
```

CSS

```
.cell {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I tried a static solution with fixed cell width and height, which worked. 
However, when I tried using dynamic sizes, it doesn't display the divs anymore.
How would I make this work?

I'm trying to make a grid of cell divs inside the grid div with no gaps in-between.

I just tried using display:inline-block, but that gives me extra space every new line.

Comment: You are trying to modify CSS properties of elements that don't exist. First append the elements then select them!

Comment: Ah! I just moved the .css() to after the loop, but now I get a long red column of divs. Nvm, that has to do with display. http://jsfiddle.net/prashanthcr/cv5c3cah/1/

Comment: You haven't mentioned in your question what should happen instead! Why are you generating 100 "cell"s?

Comment: Fixed! I'm trying to make a grid using divs inside a div. Since it's 10 a side, that's 100 ".cell" in total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using

```
float: left;
```

instead of changing display.

http://jsfiddle.net/prashanthcr/cv5c3cah/2/